# Find movieclips and modify them

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I want to find all movie clips in movieclip or root, and modify them (x, y, scale,..), is it possible if they dont have instance names?

```
 for(var i:int = 0; i < MovieClip(root).numChildren; i++) {
 trace (MovieClip(root).getChildAt(i).name);    
 }

 //it trace:
 instance1
 instance2
 instance3
 instance4
```

So how to control them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cycle all the children of your MC like this

```
for (var i:int=0; i<root.numChildren; i++) {
     if (root.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip) {
          root.getChildAt(i).scaleX = 0.5 // for example
     }
}
```